# Неправильное выравнивание по вертикали

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, button

Есть страница, в которой кнопка с лупой расположена чуть выше инпута "Поиск по товарам".

[image: vertalign]

Есть код

```css
.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
}

#SearchBlock {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

#SearchBlock input {
    height: 100%;
}

#SearchBlock button {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindowright">
                    <div class="crosslineright">
                        <div class="close">&times;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
                        <span id="SearchBlock">
                            <span>
                                <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <button id="SearchButton"><svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg></button>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Подскажите как добиться одинакового вертикального расположения инпута и кнопки.

Попробовал как в ответе и получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как выровнять последний вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
}

#SearchBlock {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

#SearchBlock input{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindowright">
                    <div class="crosslineright">
                        <div class="close">&times;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
                        <span id="SearchBlock">
                            <span>
                                <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <button id="SearchButton"><svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg></button>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Подскажите как добиться полного выравнивания (см. отредактированный вопрос).

Comment: Коде нет, попробую в слепую, добавьте для кнопки `height: 100%`

Comment: Добавьте для `#SearchBlock` свойство `display: flex;`

Comment: добавил `display:flex` для `#SearchBlock` - не помогло.

Comment: https://codepen.io/DanilPon/pen/mdmmpgQ